# Is classic load balancer going to be discontinued by aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, iaas, aws-elb

Can some one help me with the fact is aws going to discontinue classic load balancer in future??

I have checked many documents but non of it clearly mentions about it.

Answer (score 4):

As Edcel Cabrera Vista says, there's no real way to know if AWS will discontinue a product or not, until they actually tell us. They haven't told us that Classic Load Balancers are being discontinued.

They are, however, discontinuing EC2 Classic Networking, and I think that leads to some confusion. They both have "classic" in their name and load balancers are usually thought of as networking. So you'd think they were the same thing or at least related somehow.

But no, "Classic Load Balancers" are different than "EC2 Classic Networking". It's only EC2 Classic Networking that is being discontinued right now. Classic Load Balancers are not at this time being discontinued. AWS has not addressed this confusion, but from [the announcement in July of this year](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-classic-is-retiring-heres-how-to-prepare/), they say that a Classic Load Balancer in EC2 Classic will have to be migrated to a Classic Load Balancer in a VPC. If your Classic Load Balancers are already in a VPC, then they won't be affected.

AWS provides a [Bash shell script](https://github.com/aws-samples/ec2-classic-resource-finder/blob/main/Classic-Resource-Finder.sh) you can run to find any EC2 Classic Networking resources you might have out there. To run the script you need to have AWS CLI set up, including having your credentials set. Then run the script. It'll spit out a bunch of csv files with any lingering EC2 Classic Resources you might have out there, as well as a csv file that tells you whether your account is enabled for EC2 Classic Networking. If yours is not, and you have nothing listed in the "Classic_CLBs.csv" file, then you have nothing to worry about. Hooray!

Comment: I've moved some classic ELBs from the classic network to a VPC. The script does not show the Classic ELBs when in a VPC, so you can assume that ELB classic is not to be discontinued as long at it is in the scope of a VPC network. I mean, only will be discontinued the Classic ELBs with the following VPC ID: "EC2-Classic network"

Answer (score 2):

There is no exact answer if a service is going to be discontinued by aws. However there are few ways for you to have a peace of mind regarding those thoughts because it's a possible scenario in the future as well.

AWS offers documentation for you to migrate the classic load balancer to their new solutions having this document will help you think to adopt properly & more agile. And it gives more feature to your application.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/migrate-to-application-load-balancer.html

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there are any plans to discontinue it, however, it is heavily advised against using it for any new load balancer.

It was primarily targeted for EC2 Classic

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the aws official article saying "classic load balancer is discontinued or deprecated".
However, I found this aws official article ["Migrate your Classic Load Balancer"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/migrate-to-application-load-balancer.html).

I'm not sure the article implies "classic load balancer is discontinued or deprecated". But at least I can see the article implies "You better use new load balancer". Actually, application load balancer(new) is better than classic load balancer(old) as long as I tried both.

In addition, a similar thing happens for "Launch Template"(new) and "Launch Configuration"(old) on EC2. Then, there is no aws official article saying "Launch Configuration(old) is discontinued or deprecated".

But there are aws official articles ["Replacing a launch configuration with a launch template"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/replace-launch-config.html) and ["Launch templates"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/LaunchTemplates.html).

In both artcles, "Launch Template"(new) is recommended to use actually.

Moreover, the prices of newer instance types are cleaper than older ones.
It will implies "You better use newer instance types".

Answer (score 1):

AWS is [Retiring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/migrate-classic-load-balancer.html) the EC2 Classic LB by August 2022, after the Aug 15 will they still work without any issue and is it just the support for classic LB stopped?

I can not comment this so I'm posting this here.

Comment: This is only true for classic load balancers _in EC2-Classic networking mode_. That is, ELBv1 not inside a VPC. If your AWS account was created after 2013, then by default you cannot have made an ELBv1 outside of a VPC. ELBv1 inside of VPCs is not deprecated.

Comment: This 1000000 times over ^^^. It's very confusing naming but "Classic Load Balancers" aren't going away on 8/15/22. Only those that are not within a VPC (e.g. they are part of EC2-Classic).

Comment: ELBv1 is still available if you use VPC networking.